# realloc() leaking memory

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks

I have a function which adds a character to a string:

```
void AddChToString(char **str,char ch){
    int len=(*str)?strlen(*str):0;
    (*str)=realloc(*str, len+2);
    (*str)[len]=ch;
    (*str)[len+1]='\0';
}
```

Instruments (on the mac) and Valgrind are indicating that the line: (*str)=realloc(*str, len+2) is leaking memory. Is this an implementation issue with realloc? Or am I using it improperly?

Here is the output from Valgrind:

```
==39230== 6 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 7
==39230==    at 0x100018B2D: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==39230==    by 0x100002259: AddChToString (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230==    by 0x10000477B: QueryMapFromString (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230==    by 0x100684CD2: ???
==39230==    by 0x100001FB0: RequestHandler (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230==    by 0x100065535: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==39230==    by 0x1000653E8: thread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==39230== 
==39230== 9 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 7
==39230==    at 0x100018B2D: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==39230==    by 0x100002259: AddChToString (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230==    by 0x10000298E: ParseHTTPRequest (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230==    by 0x100004151: OpenRoutesFile (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230==    by 0x10000142B: main (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230== 
==39230== 45 bytes in 5 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 7
==39230==    at 0x100018B2D: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==39230==    by 0x100002259: AddChToString (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230==    by 0x10000298E: ParseHTTPRequest (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230==    by 0x100001EB4: RequestHandler (in ./OpenOtter)
==39230==    by 0x100065535: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==39230==    by 0x1000653E8: thread_start (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==39230== 
==39230== LEAK SUMMARY:
==39230==    definitely lost: 60 bytes in 7 blocks
==39230==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==39230==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==39230==    still reachable: 1,440 bytes in 4 blocks
==39230==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why the pointer to pointer if you're not using the first indirection anyway?

Comment: What instruments are you using? If you're using something that just shows virtual memory size, then its a non-issue (well, at least not an issue with `realloc()` ... that code, on the other hand)

Comment: if realloc() returns NULL, you lose pointer to memory.

Comment: @delnan: `realloc` could return an address different from the one you passed to it. Without using double indirection, function caller wouldn't get new address.

Comment: @delnan: `(*str)=realloc(`... uses `*str` as an lvalue, so a `char*` parameter would not work the same.

Comment: "Is this an implementation issue with realloc?" **No** "Am I using it improperly?" **Yes**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call to realloc itself does not leak memory. You should make sure that the memory for reallocated string is released with free after it's not needed any more.

Comment: It turned out that the debuggers were telling me where the memory was allocated, not where it was leaked.

Comment: @Maz: where it's allocated is where it's leaked if you never free the block (at least that's pretty much the only way a tool can identify it).  So you're saying that the pointers passed to `AddChToString()` were never freed elsewhere, right?

Comment: Yes that's what i was saying. I don't have much experience with memory debuggers, I thought that the information explained where the last known reference to the memory went out of scope, not where the memory was allocated.

Answer (score 9):

Is your instrumentation indicating that there's an actual leak or that there's a potential leak?

Using `realloc()` like you are will leak memory *if* `realloc()` fails.  In that case, it'll return `NULL` but will not free the original block.  So you will have lost the pointer to the block and cannot free it (unless the pointer is stored elsewhere).

But this should be a rare occurrence (ie., when you've exhausted memory).

If that's what your tools are complaining about, you  should be able to fix the leak warning with something like:

```
void AddChToString(char **str,char ch){
    int len=(*str)?strlen(*str):0;
    char* tmp = realloc(*str, len+2);

    if (!tmp) {
        // whatever error handling is appropriate
    }

    (*str)=tmp;
    (*str)[len]=ch;
    (*str)[len+1]='\0';
}
```

Comment: Run-time leak checker like `valgrind` don't do this kind of checking, as far as I know.

Comment: @peoro - when the answer was written there was no specific information about the tools used, their output, or where they were run-time instrumentation or static check tools (lint or similar).

Comment: even the original message posted 55 minutes ago was talking about Valgrind. Anyway I didn't mean to say you are wrong or anything else, just adding a little (pedantic maybe?) observation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about implementation issues about `realloc`, but there is surely an opportunity for memory leak in this code: from the `realloc` manpage:

> If **`realloc()`** fails the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved.

and, since `realloc` returns `NULL` when it fails, if it fails you lose your only pointer to the already allocated memory block, so you have a memory leak.

To avoid the problem, you should do:

```
char * temp=realloc(*str, len+2);
if(temp==NULL)
{
    /* handle the error in some way */
}
else
    *str=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

try reallocating using a separate variable, then calling strcpy to get the str variable into that space, like this:

```
void AddChToString(char **str,char ch){
char *blah;
int len=(*str)?strlen(*str):0;
blah=realloc(NULL, len+2);
strcpy(blah, str); 
(*str)[len]=ch;   
(*str)[len+1]='\0'; }
```