# Raw Heap String

Tags: c

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of heap-management in C. The following code compiles w/o warnings and runs w/o errors.

```
char* string_make(char* text) {
      size_t len = strlen(text) + 1;
      char* str = malloc(len);
      memcpy(str, text, len);
      return str;
}

char* string_concat(char* x, char* y) {
      size_t len_x = strlen(x);
      size_t len_y = strlen(y);
      x = realloc(x, len_x + len_y + 1);
      memcpy(x+len_x, y, len_y+1);
      return x;
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
      char* first = string_make("funny");
      char* second = string_make(" duck");
      char* third = string_make("! c++");
      //
      printf("%s\n", string_concat(first, second));
      printf("%s\n", string_concat(first, third));
      //
      free(first);
      free(second);
      free(third);
}
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is string_make() doing anything illegal or undefined?
2. Is string_concat() doing anything illegal or undefined?

I just want to create a simple heap string, which could be increased/decreased at different stages of program as per requirements.

Thanks.

EDIT:

If I change string_concat() calls in main to the following:

```
first = string_concat(first, second);
first = string_concat(first, third);
```

would it make things legit?

Comment: The way you use `realloc()`, you leak memory if `realloc()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @EOF Technically, it is still in the `first` pointer... I think it is fine. What would you do in case of NULL ?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Which means this code exhibits use-after-free in turn. After `realloc(x, ...)` in `string_concat()`, the pointer `first` in `main()` points to a `free()`'d object, making both the second `realloc()` and the `free(first)` in `main()` undefined behavior.

Comment: @EOF Will `x` get freed if `realloc` fails?

Comment: The second `string_concat` call will be using an invalid `first` pointer value if the previous `string_concat` had realloced it.

Comment: @kaylum Ah, that.. Right.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, if `realloc()` fails, the allocation the old pointer pointed to is left unchanged.

Comment: The problem is that `first` in `main` is not being updated, so the second `string_concat` call is invalid, as is the `free(first)` call.

Comment: I've left out error-checking, intentionally, to keep the code short.

Comment: @ThunderThunder You may have missed some of the points. The `main` code is wrong even when there are no errors in the function calls.

Comment: Neither of the memory allocations actually check to see if they were successful.  That's a bad idea.

Comment: As it stands, "Is my code ok?" is a closer fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Note: candidate code simplification: `memcpy(str, text, len); return str;` --> `return memcpy(str, text, len);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring error checking (after `malloc` and `realloc`), all you need to do is replace these two lines in `main`:

```
printf("%s\n", string_concat(first, second));
printf("%s\n", string_concat(first, third));
```

with these lines

```
first = string_concat(first, second);    
printf("%s\n", first);
first = string_concat(first, third);
printf("%s\n", first);
```

The reason is that arguments are passed by value in C. So updating `x` in the `string_concat` does not update variable `first` in `main`. So the code needs to update `first` using the return value from the function.

Now, you may be confused because you tested your code and it seemed to work. That's because your final string was only 16 bytes, including the NUL terminator. Most modern implementations of `malloc` will round up the size to a multiple of 16 (or some larger power of 2). That means that all three calls to `string_make` returned pointers to memory regions of 16 bytes, even though you requested less. And that also means that `realloc` can expand the buffer without moving it. As the man page explains

> If there is **not enough room to enlarge the memory allocation**
>   pointed to by ptr, realloc() creates a new allocation, copies as much
>   of the old data pointed to by ptr as will fit to the new allocation,
>   frees the old allocation, and returns a pointer to the allocated
>   memory.

In your case, there *was* enough room to enlarge the memory allocation, so `realloc` returned the same pointer that was passed in. And as a result, your code would appear to work even though it has a serious flaw.

Answer (score 3):

string_make is fine.

string_concat is not.  It reallocates x, which possibly means that a bigger chunk of memory is allocated elsewhere, and the original chunk of memory is marked as free.  However, functions in C do not change their arguments, therefore when string_concat returns, x possibly points to a location which is marked as free.

Answer (score 0):

`string_concat()`: If using `realloc()` I would pass the address of the pointer to the string  which has to be `realloc`-ed, but return the reallocated string itself. So I would avoid the return value pointing at location possibly marked as `free`. In case realloc returns NULL, function returns pointer to the original string.

```
char* string_concat(char** x, char* y) {
  size_t len_x = strlen(*x);
  size_t len_y = strlen(y);
  char *temp = realloc(*x, len_x + len_y + 1);
  if(!temp) return *x;     //or do some more appropriate error handling
  memcpy(temp+len_x, y, len_y+1);
  *x = temp;
  return *x;
}
```

and

```
  printf("%s\n", string_concat(&first, second));
  printf("%s\n", string_concat(&first,  third));
  free(first);
  free(second);
  free(third);
```

It is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548385/realloc-leaking-memory).

Comment: Your code still has potential for memory leaks. And there is little use using double indirection. OP already returns the new pointer.

Comment: @Olaf - answer revised

Comment: Removed the DV, but I still think it is not really elegant, because you "return" the same object twice without actual need.

Comment: Thanks, great that you care for _code elegance_ in the answers. It is a bit "heavy handed" indeed...

Comment: Just to clarify: By "elegance" I not primarily mean pretty looking, but more understandability and straight-forrward usage. All things which contribute to quality and maintainability. Which does not mean I bend the rules myself sometimes for various reasons ;-)

Comment: Of course, good example code has to meet all of the following demands: to be human readable, machine efficient and lean. Thanks for your clarification (-: